# Understanding RangeTableEntry in Apache AGE: Significance and Use Cases

Tags: apache-age

In the Apache AGE codebase, the acronym "rte" is frequently used and returned as the return type in many functions. I understand that it stands for "RangeTableEntry," but I'm struggling to comprehend its significance and the scenarios where it's necessary.

For instance, the following function returns RangeTableEntry as its output type:

`static RangeTblEntry *transform_cypher_optional_match_clause(cypher_parsestate *cpstate, cypher_clause *clause)`

However, I'm encountering "couldn't find rte" errors in some functions, which suggests that I'm missing some crucial understanding. Could someone please explain what RangeTableEntry is and why it's important in Apache AGE code? Also, what are some use cases where it's necessary?

Answer (score 2):

A range table entry refers to a relation (table) used within an SQL query. It could also refer to a subquery within the query. It's a data structure that contains information about the table alias, column definitions etc.

Check out the definition under `nodes/parsenodes.h` to see all the info contained within the struct.

Here's something taken from the [official docs:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/rules.html#QUERYTREE)

> The range table is a list of relations that are used in the query. In
> a SELECT statement these are the relations given after the FROM key
> word.
>
> Every range table entry identifies a table or view and tells by which
> name it is called in the other parts of the query. In the query tree,
> the range table entries are referenced by number rather than by name,
> so here it doesn't matter if there are duplicate names as it would in
> an SQL statement. This can happen after the range tables of rules have
> been merged in. The examples in this chapter will not have this
> situation.

Answer (score 1):

According to the postgreSQL documentation

> The range table is a list of relations that are used in the query. In a SELECT statement these are the relations given after the FROM key word.

> Every range table entry identifies a table or view and tells by which name it is called in the other parts of the query. In the query tree, the range table entries are referenced by number rather than by name, so here it doesn't matter if there are duplicate names as it would in an SQL statement. This can happen after the range tables of rules have been merged in.

So it is a data structure that holds information about the query.

Answer (score 1):

RangeTableEntry (rte) is the internal representation of the relations that you mention after the `FROM` clause. It is one of the components of the `Query Tree` which is returned by the Parser in postgreSQL.

When you run this query

```
SELECT name, age FROM users;
```

The RangeTableEntry (rte) would represent the `users` table. That rte would then be used by the query processing system to determine the schema of the table and to access the requested columns.

Answer (score 0):

RangeTblEntry a list of all tables (and possibly other data sources) that are involved in a query. When a query is parsed in PostgreSQL, one of the steps involves generating a range table. This is a list where each entry, a RangeTblEntry, represents a table or other relation that is referenced in the query. This can include actual physical tables in the database, subqueries, joins, and function calls that return sets of rows, among other things.

RangeTblEntry is used in any part of the system that deals with query processing. This could include parsing, rewriting, planning, or executing queries, among other things.

"couldn't find rte" error means that the system is trying to find a RangeTblEntry for a particular relation but is not able to. This could be because the relation isn't referenced in the query, or because there's an issue with how the query is being parsed or transformed.

Answer (score 0):

I recently did some extensive research on RTE. RangeTableEntry (RTE) is used to describe tables or subqueries in a query. It includes names, aliases, columns, join criteria, and access methods for these entities as well as other metadata. RTE provides details about the organisation and connections between tables and subqueries, which aids in query optimisation and execution.
You can also look into the srtuct of RTE and see what it consists of

```
typedef struct RangeTblEntry
{
    pg_node_attr(custom_read_write, custom_query_jumble)

    NodeTag     type;

    RTEKind     rtekind;

    Oid         relid;
    char        relkind;
    int         rellockmode;
    struct TableSampleClause *tablesample;
    Index       perminfoindex;

    Query      *subquery;
    bool        security_barrier;

    JoinType    jointype;
    int         joinmergedcols;
    List       *joinaliasvars;
    List       *joinleftcols;
    List       *joinrightcols;

    Alias      *join_using_alias;

    List       *functions;
    bool        funcordinality;

    TableFunc  *tablefunc;

    List       *values_lists;

    char       *ctename;
    Index       ctelevelsup;
    bool        self_reference;

    List       *coltypes;
    List       *coltypmods;
    List       *colcollations;

    char       *enrname;
    Cardinality enrtuples;

    Alias      *alias;
    Alias      *eref;
    bool        lateral;
    bool        inh;
    bool        inFromCl;
    List       *securityQuals;
} RangeTblEntry;
```

This should help you in understanding RTE in AGE

Answer (score 0):

RTE stands for” RangeTblEntry“ is a structure in PostgreSQL the name “range table” in the PostgreSQL
source code refers not only to tables, subqueries, results of joins but also any record that a SQL statement operates on. It keeps data of these tables, subqueries etc. This RTE struct has various fields
but some of the important fields are subquery pointer of type Query to hold the data of subquery, jointype of type JoinType to hold the join information and some other Boolean flags to keep the record
of different Boolean values. This information is required in further processing of queries.

You can check [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/rules.html#QUERYTREE) to read more about it.

> The range table is a list of relations that are used in the query. In
> a SELECT statement these are the relations given after the FROM key
> word.